# json_encode does not display HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am bringing some data from the database, and some of them have `HTML` tags such as "`<p>Hello</ p>`". However, when step data through to return it shows json_encode in "`&lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;`". What should I do to return the same data that was saved in the database?

PHP:

```
$retorna = array(
    'conteudo_programatico' => $conteudo_programatico,
    'investimento' => $investimento,
    'coordenacao' => $coordenacao,
    'importante' => $importante
);

echo json_encode($retorna);
```

AJAX:

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: id},
            url: "paginas/ajax/form.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $("#cursos").slideDown();
                $(".call-conteudo").text(data['conteudo_programatico']);
                $(".call-investimento").text(data['investimento']);
                $(".call-coordenacao").text(data['coordenacao']);
                $(".call-importante").text(data['importante']);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: json-encode doesn't do html encoding. if those chars are coming through as html entities, then something ELSE is doing the encoding, long before json_encode() ever got close to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of jQuery's `.text()`:

```
$(".call-conteudo").text(data['conteudo_programatico']);
// etc.
```

According to the [manual](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

> We need to be aware that this method escapes the string provided as
>   necessary so that it will render correctly in HTML. To do so, it calls
>   the DOM method .createTextNode(), does not interpret the string as
>   HTML
>
> ...
>
> The code `$( "div.demo-container" ).text( "<p>This is a test.</p>" );`
>   will produce the following DOM output:

```
 1 <div class="demo-container">
 2   &lt;p&gt;This is a test.&lt;/p&gt;
 3 </div>
```

You need [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/):

```
$(".call-conteudo").html(data['conteudo_programatico']);
// etc.
```